# How to get Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) to see USB modem device (Arduino)?

Tags: mac, osx-mountain-lion, arduino

Normally, plugging in the Arduino to a Mac creates `/dev/tty.usbmodemXXXX` but on Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) it does not. How can I get this operating system to see the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many sources that come up in Google searches say that you don't need to install the FTDI drivers for newer Arduinos (Since the Uno or Mega). If you have an Arduino Mega this may lead you to believe you don't need them. However, some older revisions of the Arduino Mega do in fact need these drivers, so if you don't see the device in `/dev/tty.usbmodemXXXX` try installing the FTDI drivers.

Get the latest drivers from here:
http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm

Comment: The newer Arduinos don't have FTDI devices on them, so this would not help. Arduinos now use an ATmega16U2 as the USB-serial IC.

Comment: Well installing it worked for *my* Arduino Mega. According to the sources I read from Google searches Uno and Mega don't need this, but I did for my Mega, so I generalised them together. How can I improve the answer to be more accurate? If the Uno doesn't need it but the Mega does, maybe just removing the Uno will make it right? Or are there multiple versions of the Mega, some which need it and others which don't?

Comment: You probably have an older Mega. They *used* to use a FTDI device, and I don't think they've changed the Mega name, despite the board revisions.

Comment: Ok, I've edited that in. Thanks for helping to improve the answer.

Comment: From browsing the arduino site, It turns out there are a bunch of versions of the "Arduino Mega". There is the Arduino Mega, the Arduino Mega 2560, the Arduino Mega 2560 R3, etc... Their naming scheme sucks.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to examine the board and look for an FTDI part, vs another Atmel part?

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Yes.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this on my OS X 10.8 machine. I did in fact need to install the drivers you mentioned for my Arduino Nano but not for my Uno 3. A quick re-launch of the Arduino IDE caused the Nano to show up in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced inconsistent connections to a Due board with OS X 10.8.2 when using a single USB cable to supply power and communications. You might try using a second USB connection on boards that support it or an external power supply.

Answer (score 0):

There is something fishy with how the Due interacts with OSX. You can get it to work by pressing the erase button between sketch downloads:

http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,142550.0.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading these drivers worked for me:

http://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/pages/usbtouartbridgevcpdrivers.aspx

My Arduino Mega 2560 was actually a MultiWii PRO Flight Controller from Hobby King.

Although the clock speed seems to be off a little.

Answer (score 0):

I have an Osepp Uno R3 Plus.  Although it's an Uno, it uses the FTDI chip, so installing the FTDI driver was what it needed.

Answer (score -1):

I've manage to see /dev/tty.usbserial-* after installing above mentioned FTDI driver http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm. This is on MacOS 10.8.5, Arduino IDE 1.0.5, and Arduino Mega with ARMEGA1289 16AU 0849 chip.